# How can I parse the winmail.dat file?

Tags: c#, .net, tnef, winmail.dat

Simple question. I have a C# application that access an IMAP server using the [AE.Net.Mail](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail) library to retrieve messages and attached files. Sometimes, when a message is sent from Outlook the attachments are contained in a file named winmail.dat. That is a file in the [TNEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format) format.

Is there a library or any other way for my application to "unpack" theses files so I can get the attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this tool](http://www.eolsoft.com/freeware/winmail_opener/) that can be controled from the command line to extract attacheemnts, from a TNEF file, but I would really prefer a library that would run "in process".

Comment: I accepted my own answer because that is what I eventually used, but feel this is more an effective hack rather than a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've just recently implemented TNEF support in [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) which is based on Microsoft's Exchange TNEF API, thus allowing full access to all of the data contained within.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and ended up creating an entire email library for .NET called OpaqueMail.

It has support for parsing TNEF-encoded files (e.g. Winmail.dat) via its TnefEncoding class.

[Check out this example.](http://opaquemail.org/library/tutorial/#tnef)

```
// Instantiate a TNEF Encoding object to process the byte array "tnefEncoddedBytes".
TnefEncoding tnefEncoding = new TnefEncoding(tnefEncodedBytes);

// Loop through the TNEF-encoded attachments, outputting their names, content types, and sizes.
foreach (MimePart mimePart in tnefEncoding.MimeAttachments)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MIME Part Name: " + mimePart.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("MIME Part Content Type: " + mimePart.ContentType);
    Console.WriteLine("MIME Part Size: " + mimePart.BodyBytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: No longer maintained in favor of MimeKit by jstedfast

Comment: Downvoted to give preference to MimeKit answer. The above link no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search leads to this : [Yerase's TNEF Stream Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ytnef/)

The project has source code, you can either reproduce it in C# or make a small C# (or better, C++/CLI)  wrapper to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If its for Linux platform, then you could use tnef tool

[TNEF](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tnef)

Usage to get the Body from winmail.dat :  **tnef -w --save-body winmail.dat**
Usage to extract only the attachments from winmail.dat file:  **tnef winmail.dat**

Tnef extracts the Body/atatchments into our current directory where we are running this tool. Or else we could give the -C DIR, --directory=DIR to save them into the specified path

Answer (score -1):

[TnefReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.contenttypes.tnef.tnefreader%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) could be of help.

Comment: I found this during my research. Unfortunately, the dll containing the Microsoft.Exchange namespace is not redistributable.